# Replace comma seperated rows in html with table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html which comma seperated rows which I would like to replace with table. I plan to add this code to a chrome extension so that when user clicks on that extension, the page is reloaded with comma separated rows displayed as table. How can I do that?
Number of numbers in each row is same. 
Some values might be blank (1,2,3,,,4,5)
Each row is seperated by new line.

```html
<div class="formattedMsg">My execution: 
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15

Total time : x secs
Time per instance : y secs

</div>
```

Comment: Can there be different number of numbers in the comma-separated string?

Ex: `1,2,3\n
4, 5, 6, 7\n
1`

Comment: what is the separator between 5 & 6 , 10 and 11

Comment: @Tushar the number of numbers in each string is same though some might not have values 
for e.g.. 1,2,3,,,,,4,5 but number of commas will be same. Number of columns should be (number of commas + 1)

Comment: @brk separator between 5&6 is new line.

Comment: [`let nums = document.querySelector('.formattedMsg').innerHTML.match(/(\d+)(,\d+)+/g);

let html = `<table>`;
nums.forEach(num => html += '<tr>' + num.replace(/(\d+),?/g, (m, n) => `<td>${n}</td>`) + '</tr>');
html += '</table>';
document.body.innerHTML += html;`](https://jsfiddle.net/c6ronejm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you want to convert a CSV into a table through Javascript on the fly.

```
let origClass = document.getElementById("formattedMsg").innerHTML.split("\n");
let res = "<table>";
orig.forEach(function (item) {

  res += "<tr>";
  let line = item.split(",");
  line.forEach(function (item){
     res += "<td>"+item+"</td>";
  });
  res += "</tr>";
});
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="formattedMsg">My execution: 
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15

Total time : x secs
Time per instance : y secs

</div>
```

Comment: Also I have quiet a few CSVs preceeded by 
<div class="formattedMsg">My execution1: ...
<div class="formattedMsg">My execution2: .. 
<div class="formattedMsg">My execution3: .. 

How can I grab/distinguish between execution1, execution 2, etc?

Comment: @Jitu getElementByClassName, get all elements, and loop through them